# matlab scatter plot using colorbar for 2 vectors

Tags: matlab

I have a two columns of data. X = Model values of NOx concentrations and Y = Observations of NOx concentrations. Now, I want to scatter plot X, Y (markers varying with colors) as well as the colourbar which would show me the counts (i.e. number of data points in that range). X and Y are daily data for a year, i.e. 365 rows.

Please help me. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
I have attached a sample image.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a scatter plot with graduated marker colours in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935768/how-do-i-create-a-scatter-plot-with-graduated-marker-colours-in-matlab)

Comment: the example has 3 columns, i have only two..X and Y

Comment: Do I create a third columns with the number of data points in that concentration range ?.. but the length of the 3rd vector isnt same as X or Y

Comment: The color information, i.e. the "Counts" - how is that stored? Is it also a vector with the same size as X and Y?

Comment: I haven't created any color information. That's where I am struggling .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the real problem is creating the color information, which is, creating a *bivariate histogram*. Luckily, MATLAB has a function, [`hist3`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html), for that in the Statistics & Machine Learning Toolbox. The syntax is

```
[N,C] = hist3(X,nbins)
```

where `X` is a *m*-by-2 matrix containing the data, and `nbins` is a 1-by-2 vector containing the number of bins in each dimension. The return value `N` is a matrix of size `nbins(1)`-by-`nbins(2)`, and contains the histogram data. `C` is a 1-by-2 cell array, containing the bin centers in both dimensions.

```
% Generate sample data
X = randn(10000, 1);
Y = X + rand(10000, 1);

% Generate histogram
[N,C] = hist3([X,Y], [100,100]);

% Plot
imagesc(C{1},C{2},N);
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
colormap(flipud(pink));
colorbar;
```

**Result:**

[image: Resulting figure]